# How can I use withTheme HOC on two components?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm using a custom HOC called `withTheme` on a React native app.

I use it like this way:

```
import React from 'react';
import { withTheme } from 'react-native-elements';
// some code
export const MyComponent: React.FC<MyComponentProps> = ({
  relationshipStyle
}) => {
  // some code
  return (
    <Text style={relationshipStyle}>hello</Text>
    {newComponent}// and here I'll put a new component
  );
};

export default withTheme(MyComponent, 'MyComponent');
```

But now, I want to add another component in the same file which have to use too `withTheme` HOC. How can I do it?

I need something like:

```
// the code is wrong, I just want to show what I'm trying to get
export const withTheme(newComponent({
  statusStyle
}), 'newComponent) => {
  return (
    <Text
      style={statusStyle}
    >
      new component
    </Text>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to export both components. Of course, you can only have 1 default export, so you have to name at least the other one. For example:

```js
const OtherComponent = withTheme(_OtherComponent, 'OtherComponent');
export OtherComponent;
```